# Where can I get the original Team Fortress?

Tags: team-fortress

I really like Team Fortress 2, and would like to play the game that started it all. After some intense searching, I couldn't find it. Have any ideas where I can grab it from?

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is [available for purchase](http://store.steampowered.com/app/20/) from Steam, under the name *Team Fortress Classic*. At the time of writing, it costs $4.99/€4.99/£2.99 in the primary regions.

You also get it as part of the [Half-Life 1 Anthology](http://store.steampowered.com/sub/40/), the [Half-Life Complete](http://store.steampowered.com/sub/715/) pack, and of course the [Valve Complete Pack](http://store.steampowered.com/sub/18702/).

Comment: @JeffreyLin: [The Orange Box](http://store.steampowered.com/sub/469/) doesn't contain TF1, only TF2.

Comment: The original is a mod for Quake. Team Fortress Classic is a remake of the *original* mod.

Answer (score 8):

The original Team Fortress is a Quake mod, of which version 2.8 is [still available online](http://www.moddb.com/mods/team-fortress/downloads/team-fortress-28-release) here.  There are also modded versions of the original, such as MegaTF and CustomTF.

Team Fortress Classic is a remake of the original Team Fortress for the Half-Life engine and as mentioned by Michael Madsen, is still sold on Steam.  It uses different players models and some of the game mechanics have changed a bit.

Honestly, though, you're better off sticking with TF2.